# Часовые пояса

Tags: часовые-пояса, php, время

Вот добавил юзер из Украины материал, и в бд занеслась серверная дата и время. Например, 2012-10-10 15:25

А я, юзер из России, должен видеть время добавления - московское, китайский юзер - китайское. Россия например 16:25, Китай 20:45

Какие функции нужны для этого? Или что вообщем нужно для такой реализации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](http://ipgeobase.ru/),
вот:

[image]

и javaScript.

Comment: @istem, как дату преобразовать то, чтобы каждая страна видела свое? Я это не пойму.

 JS для чего тут? :)

Comment: Элементарно же. 
Вариант 1: Определяется IP клиента, по IP определяется регион, по региону определяется часовое смещение относительно сервера. Смещение отправляется клиенту, на клиенте корректируется дата new Date() с учётом полученного смещения. 
Вариант 2: Серверное время отправляется клиенту. На клиенте тут же получаете new Date() - определяете часовой пояс относительно сервера. Устанавливаете куку с текущим смещением. На сервере, при генерации страниц, используете это смещение.

Comment: @istem, а нельзя без js обойтись? Все делать на сервере. Например в бд запишется юникстайм серверного времени. Далее если поставить set diapazone London,  то добавленный юникс будет выводить Лондовские значения?

Comment: Смотрите сами, как вам удобнее. Я всего лишь посоветовал.

Answer (score 0):

Всего-навсего надо ставить нужную таймзону для каждого пользователя..  Правда не помню, только в PHP или в MySQL тоже надо..

Comment: @Photon, сначала ведь страну нужно получить, а потом уж)

Comment: Согласен..  Но какой вопрос, такой и ответ..